# Clojure Best Practice: When to use Metadata?

Tags: clojure

I don't mean this as a subjective question -- I am trying to understand why exactly `with-meta` is in the language. I realize it *can* be used for many purposes (so can `eval`, but its use outside specific circumstances is a sign of Bad Design). From a design perspective, what *unique* purpose does Clojure's metadata structure serve? Is it primarily for documentation? Is it sugar?

What are some strong applications for `with-meta`/`meta`? In what cases is it a bad idea? Can you give an example of the use of metadata to do something that would be impossible/difficult/tedious without it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several of the core features of the language depend on metadata:

- macros one feature that depends on metadata. A macro is a function with a bit of metadata that causes the function to run at compiletime.

  ```
  user> (meta #'when)

  {:macro true, 
   :ns #<Namespace clojure.core>, 
   :name when, :arglists ([test & body]), 
   :column 1, :added "1.0", 
   :doc "Evaluates test. If logical true, evaluates body in an implicit do.", 
   :line 471, 
   :file "clojure/core.clj"}
  ```
- Types are another feature of the language that depends on metadata. The type of something is expressed as metadata on that object.
- tests also use metadata. when you (or lein) call `run-tests` it looks at the metadata on the functions in each namespace to find the ones that are tests.

There are many more cases ranging from core of the language like types to peripheral things like n-repl/cider displaying the function arguments at the bottom of the screen while you work that use metadata. It is not a design smell to use metadata provided you are not using it to do ugly things of course ;)

Comment: Anyone know how to make code in a bullet list show up in a proper code block?

Comment: You have to indent it with 4 more spaces and put a blank line between the text of the bullet point and the code.

Comment: With respect @ArthurUlfeldt, this answer is missing the meat! Tell me some of those ugly things?

Answer (score 2):

Metadata is useful for attaching details to values that don't need it directly. For example, in a web server, you may use metadata for endpoint information on functions (e.g. does calling this function require authentication) and process them in your handler. Ring, for example, uses metadata to [check if a session should be recreated](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Sessions).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Arthur Ulfeldt mentions above, one of the *unique* features of Clojure is the use of metadata for extending protocols.  This allows you to add protocols dynamically to pretty much any object (actually any value) *after it has been created*.  As far as I am aware, this capability is not available in most other languages (possible exception of Smalltalk).

See [Extend via Metadata](https://clojure.org/reference/protocols#_extend_via_metadata) for more.

Since adding metadata in Clojure does not impact equality semantics, if adding metadata causes your application to mistakenly consider two objects to be equal, you could run into semantic problems.  This issue is domain-specific.